# Ignore auto-completion on single same filename

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Normally when I pass a filename which is the only file there in current directory with auto-completion by Tab to the command come before it then press multiple Tab(mistakenly), the same filename complete multiple times and I should delete or cancel and start again.

Is there any way to disable this behavior (without creating another file nor hidden file)?

```
ls <Tab>filename <Tab>filename <Tab>filename
```

Comment: Favourited and upvoted.  I'd be interested if some of the wizards much more powerful than me here can come up with some magic!  **;-)**

Comment: Same here. I'm sitting on the same bench as you @Fabby. This is actually something I deal with several times everyday !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use the `nospace` option for the `complete` [builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html).

First, you need to know how completion is defined for `ls`

```
$ complete -p ls
complete -F _longopt ls
```

Then you modify it by adding `-o nospace`

```
$ complete -o nospace -F _longopt ls
```

Thus, even if you hit <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> multiple times, there will be no match and no argument will be added to the command line.

*Side effect*: you need to manually append a space at the end of the line if you want to add another argument to `ls`.

To avoid this side effect you could modify the `_longopt` function in a way that prevents it from matching the same argument twice (it might not be straightforward).

**How to apply this to other commands and to make it permanent**

Appending a trailing space after a match is the default behavior. I don't know if there's a way other than using `-o nospace` when specifying completion rules with `complete`.

Moreover, keep in mind, that completion rules are specified somewhere, even for builtin commands (on my laptop in this folder: `/usr/share/bash-completion`).
If you look at the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash-completion` you'll find where completions are defined for `ls`:

```
complete -F _longopt a2ps awk base64 bash bc bison cat chroot colordiff cp \
  csplit cut date df diff dir du enscript env expand fmt fold gperf \
  grep grub head irb ld ldd less ln ls m4 md5sum mkdir mkfifo mknod \
  mv netstat nl nm objcopy objdump od paste pr ptx readelf rm rmdir \
  sed seq sha{,1,224,256,384,512}sum shar sort split strip sum tac tail tee \
  texindex touch tr uname unexpand uniq units vdir wc who
```

You see that the same rules apply for a whole bunch of different commands (such as `cp`,`mv`,`rm`...), so if you modify this by adding `-o nospace`, the changing will affect `ls` and all this other commands.

If you're not comfortable with modifying global settings (you'll need root privileges), you can write them to `~/.bash_completion` (create this file, if not present), like this

```
complete -F _longopt -o nospace a2ps awk base64 bash bc bison cat chroot colordiff cp \
  csplit cut date df diff dir du enscript env expand fmt fold gperf \
  grep grub head irb ld ldd less ln ls m4 md5sum mkdir mkfifo mknod \
  mv netstat nl nm objcopy objdump od paste pr ptx readelf rm rmdir \
  sed seq sha{,1,224,256,384,512}sum shar sort split strip sum tac tail tee \
  texindex touch tr uname unexpand uniq units vdir wc who
```

If you wish to modify completions for other commands not listed here, just look up for them in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash-completion` file or `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions` folder.

Comment: I heard you, thank you for the answer. I tested it's working perfectly, what I forgot to check does it will complete on a file containing whitespaces? and is there a way that I can do this globally for auto-completion instead of modifying every commands one by one?

Comment: Yes, it will complete on a file containing whitespaces, as the default completion for `ls` does. The `nospace` option only tells Readline not to append a space after the match. Later, I will edit the answer to address your other question.