# Stop completion on certain characters

Tags: bash, zsh, autocomplete

With the **grep** command, I tend to use various combinations of **-irln** and restrict it to include one or more of the same file types **py, js, html, css**.

E.g.

```
grep -ril --include=*{html,css}
```

I'm defining a suite of aliases for various permutations of grep which I use in the following format:

```
grep.[options].[extensions]
```

I generate the alias file with a python script which iterates over combinations of options and generates around 100 aliases in this case. Here are some of them:

```
alias grep.il.html-css='grep -ril --include=*{html,css}'
alias grep.il.html-css='grep -ril --include=*{html,css}'
alias grep.il.html-js='grep -ril --include=*{html,js}'
alias grep.iln.html-js-css='grep -riln --include=*{html,js,css}'
```

(they also all exclude the node_modules dir. I hid that for brevity, but now you know why I want these aliases!)

The reason I use full stops is because thanks to completion, it feels *almost* like typing properties on objects in an IDE, but not quite, and that's what I need help with.

The tab key attempts to select the first complete command it finds. I want it to cycle through the options up until the full stop (in the current namespace if you like).

Currently (untouched Mint/Ubuntu/Debian bash defaults) if I type this:

```
grep.i
```

And hit tab, it goes straight to:

```
grep.i.css
```

Whereas I would like it not to do that, but to cycle through the options available up until the next full stop first:

```
grep.i
grep.il
grep.in
grep.iln
grep.l
grep.n
```

And when I hit . it selects that option, after which tab would then cycle through the options available from off there, such as:

```
grep.il.css
grep.il.css_html
grep.il.css_js_html
```

Is this possible? Advisable?

I'm using bash, would consider moving to zshell if that's the only way.

UPDATE:

I can improve this situation with a little hack, which is to create a stub alias for every intermediate alias, so in the above example:

```
alias grep.='echo stub'
alias grep.il.='echo stub'
```

This stops on the full stop, but completion adds a space after so I end up with:

"grep. "

at the terminal. I can still tab to cycle through the options, but need to backspace before I start typing else I get:

"grep. i"

I've looked at the option of creating custom autocompletion behaviour making it not add a space after commands which have a . in them, but that catches files too (e.g. it would mess up `main.py hello`) I'll keep digging...

Comment: really you need to have a function instead of tens of aliases. to reply for last update to avoid adding space try change completion of the command to [`complete -o nospace -F _longopt grep`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474170/72456)

Comment: Having tens of aliases instead of a function is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. As for the nospace I am unable to get that working. I've tried permutations of `complete -o nospace less` and `compopt +o nospace less` on `less` and other commands and it still always adds a space.

Comment: @αғsнιη the question you linked to seems to be about adding spaced after arguments, and doesn't seem to work for the initial command/alias itself.

Comment: I tried this with a clean install of Zsh and it works for me. Do you perhaps have some options or styles set that mess this up?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can make it work in `zsh`:

```bsh
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
bindkey '^I' complete-word

zle -C complete-word complete-word complete-word
complete-word() {
  _main_complete
  (( compstate[unambiguous_cursor] > ${#:-$PREFIX$SUFFIX}+1 )) \
  && compstate[insert]='automenu-unambiguous'
  compstate[list]='list force'
}

zstyle ':completion:*:complete:*' show-ambiguity '07'
```

Then, when you type `grep` and press <kbd>tab</kbd>, you get:
[image: grep+tab]
You can then keep pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> to cycle through the shown completions:
[image: tab again to cycle]
Or you can type one of the highlighted characters and press <kbd>tab</kbd> again to insert the next set of characters that is common to the listed completions:
[image: or press highlighted char + tab]
Then press <kbd>tab</kbd> again to show a new completion list:
[image: tab again, rinse and repeat]
Etc., etc., etc. Lather, rinse and repeat.